# Pre-rendering a lot of images in HTML5 canvas, good idea?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

A lot of things on the internet are very conflicting on how to deal with things.

Here's my situation:

I'll be building a client in javascript, using the HTML5 canvas, the canvas will contain multiple images (ranges from 20 to 5000), which will have to be drawn, they can also move (sometimes all at once).

Now I will only redraw "differences" in the screen instead of the whole screen, but still, should I pre-render the images somehow? Cases can occur where a lot of the images will be moving.

I read about pre-rendering them in an off-screen canvas, and that would help to render them again. But does that method really help me to improve the performance? I mean it is not professional at all to have a canvas for every image right?

If not, are there other good methods to help rendering everything? Or shouldn't I worry about performance?

Using multiple layers isn't an option here by the way. (actually what i described here is 1 layer of 3 already)

Kind regards 
Jonas

Comment: This is a question better suited for [Software Engineering stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Since there is no code in here this isn't really a code-related question.

Comment: You're right, thanks